# Canvas Arrowhead

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Please look at the code for Canvas arrowhead why the arrowhead disappears every time you draw a new line. And how can I fix it? sorry for my english thank you

I want this section to be used to draw matching lines. But I have a problem with arrowheads. I hope someone can help me with a problem I'm not good at and can't find a solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/liptonkingza/4vn3uyb9/1/

> Code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var storedLines = [];
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var isDown;

ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
  handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
  handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
  handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#clear").click(function() {
  storedLines.length = 0;
  redrawStoredLines();
  
});



function handleMouseDown(e) {
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
 
  isDown = true;
  startX = mouseX;
  startY = mouseY;
  
}


function arrow (p1, p2, size) {
  var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y) , (p2.x - p1.x));
  var hyp = Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  // line
  ctx.beginPath();  
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, 0);
  
  ctx.stroke();

  // triangle
  ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, size);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, -size);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}

  

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDown) {
    return;
  }
  redrawStoredLines();
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
  
  // draw the current line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
  arrow({x: startX, y: startY}, {x: mouseX, y: mouseY}, 10);
  
  ctx.stroke();
  
}




function handleMouseUp(e) {
  isDown = false;
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
 
  storedLines.push({
    x1: startX,
    y1: startY,
    x2: mouseX,
    y2: mouseY
    
  });

  redrawStoredLines();
  arrow({x: startX, y: startY}, {x: mouseX, y: mouseY}, 10);
}


function redrawStoredLines() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (storedLines.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // redraw each stored line
  for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1);
    ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x2, storedLines[i].y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
        body {
          background-color: ivory;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        canvas {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Drag to draw lines</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<br/>
<button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `redrawStoredLines` function is only drawing lines and not including the arrow.

Replace this:

```js
function redrawStoredLines() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (storedLines.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // redraw each stored line
  for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1);
    ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x2, storedLines[i].y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

With:

```js
function redrawStoredLines() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (storedLines.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // redraw each stored line
  for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
    arrow({x: storedLines[i].x1, y: storedLines[i].y1}, {x: storedLines[i].x2, y: storedLines[i].y2}, 10);
  }
}
```

---

**See it in action...**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var storedLines = [];
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var isDown;

ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
  handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
  handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
  handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#clear").click(function() {
  storedLines.length = 0;
  redrawStoredLines();
  
});



function handleMouseDown(e) {
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
 
  isDown = true;
  startX = mouseX;
  startY = mouseY;
  
}


function arrow (p1, p2, size) {
  var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y) , (p2.x - p1.x));
  var hyp = Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  // line
  ctx.beginPath();  
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, 0);
  
  ctx.stroke();

  // triangle
  ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, size);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, -size);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}

  

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDown) {
    return;
  }
  redrawStoredLines();
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
  
  // draw the current line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
  arrow({x: startX, y: startY}, {x: mouseX, y: mouseY}, 10);
  
  ctx.stroke();
  
}




function handleMouseUp(e) {
  isDown = false;
  var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
 
  storedLines.push({
    x1: startX,
    y1: startY,
    x2: mouseX,
    y2: mouseY
    
  });

  redrawStoredLines();
  arrow({x: startX, y: startY}, {x: mouseX, y: mouseY}, 10);
}


function redrawStoredLines() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (storedLines.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // redraw each stored line
  for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
    arrow({x: storedLines[i].x1, y: storedLines[i].y1}, {x: storedLines[i].x2, y: storedLines[i].y2}, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
        body {
          background-color: ivory;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        canvas {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Drag to draw lines</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<br/>
<button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>
```

Comment: Consider using the 'Copy snippet to answer' button and apply your fix there so OP can see it in action.